# Proof in Fulton's *Algebraic Curves*

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading Fulton's [algebraic curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) book on page 106 and I didn't understand this proof:

[image]
[image]

1. I didn't understand why can we assume $F_Y\neq 0$? (what $F$ irreducible has to do with this?). Afterwards Fulton says *"$F$ doesn't divide $F_Y$"* (why?), then he concludes that $F_Y(x,y)\neq 0$ (but he has already proved this!).
2. Why $d(F(x,y))=0$?

I'm sorry for these doubts, I'm almost sure these doubts are silly. Unfortunately, I really have problems with this subject.

Thanks

Comment: I think $F_Y$ is the derivative with respect to $Y$.  If this is zero then $F$ is just a function of one variable $X$.  $F$ would then be reducible unless it is degree one.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Don't forget about positive characteristic. $k$ is an arbitrary algebraically closed field here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As long as one of $F_X$ or $F_Y$ is nonzero, we can suppose $F_Y\ne 0$, and if $F_X=F_Y=0$, then either $F$ is a constant, which is not the case, since $F$ is irreducible, or $k$ has characteristic $p$ and $F$ is a polynomial in $X^p$ and $Y^p$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, the $p^{\text{th}}$ roots of all the coefficients exist, so $$F=\sum a_{ij}X^{pi}Y^{pj} = \left(\sum \sqrt[p]{a_{ij}} X^iY^j\right)^p.$$ Again since $F$ is irreducible, this is impossible. $F_Y$ has smaller $Y$ degree, so $F \nmid F_Y$. Actually he has proved $F_Y(X,Y)\ne 0$ not $F_Y(x,y)\ne 0$. You do need $F \nmid F_Y$ to conclude $F_Y(x,y)\ne 0$.
2. $F(x,y)=0$, so $d(F(x,y))=d(0)=0.$

Comment: Why $F(x,y)=0$ in the second part?

Comment: $x$ is the class of $X$ mod $F(X,Y)$, $[X]$. Similarly $y$ is $[Y]$, so $F(x,y)=F([X],[Y])=[F(X,Y)]$. However $[F(X,Y)]=[0]=0$.

Comment: I think you made a mistake: you've wrote: $$F=\sum a_{ij}X^{pi}Y^{pj} = \left(\sum \sqrt[p]{a_{ij}} X^iY^j\right)^p.$$ instead of  $$F=\sum a_{ij}X^{pi}Y^{pj} = \sum\left(\sqrt[p]{a_{ij}} X^iY^j\right)^p.$$

Comment: @user42912, actually that was intentional, in characteristic $p$, it is true that $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ by the binomial theorem, so we can pull exponents of $p$ out over sums. So I did intend to raise the whole thing to the $p$.